# library design patterns - single generic API VS specific APIs

Tags: c++, design-patterns

Working on *DailyStatsLib*, a library for getting some stats based on the day of the week.

Is it better for *DailyStatsLib* to expose

- option 1: a **single generic API**
- option 2: expose a specific API for **each day of the week**

**Option 1 (single generic API)**

- pros: simple interface and all logic is handled by *DailyStatsLib*
- cons: *AllInfoStruct* (shown below) feels like a dumping ground for info for all days (and some of that info may not be available on a given day)

main.cpp

```
//using "std::optional" because not all info may be available on a given day
struct AllInfoStruct {
  std::optional<MondayStatsInfo> monday_info; //if day is Monday, this info will be available
  std::optional<TuesdayStatsInfo> tuesday_info; //if day is Tuesday, this info will be available
  std::optional<WednesdayStatsInfo> wednesday_info; //if day is Wednesday, this info will be available
  ...
} all_info_struct; //has all necessary info for getting stats on any day of the week

Day today = dayUtil.getDay();
Stats my_stats = DailyStatsLib::Manager.getInstance().getStats(today, all_info_struct); //single generic interface
```

**Option 2 (day-specific API)**

- pros: APIs are more focused and easier to understand and test. Not much is hidden.
- cons: **Is main.cpp doing part of the work
  that DailyStatsLib should really be doing?**

main.cpp

```
Stats my_stats;
Day today = dayUtil.getDay();
if(today == e_day_Monday){ 
    MondayStatsInfo ms;
    my_stats = DailyStatsLib::Monday.getInstance().getStats(ms);
}else if(today== e_day_Tuesday){
    TuesdayStatsInfo ts;
    my_stats = DailyStatsLib::Tuesday.getInstance().getStats(ts);
}else if(today== e_day_Wednesday){
    WednesdayStatsInfo ws;
    my_stats = DailyStatsLib::Wednesday.getInstance().getStats(ws);
}
...
```

Comment: First option looks better, but returned object should be something more generic. Maybe json with keys and values? Or unordered map with keys and values? If you can afford to make it slightly more memory consuming.

Comment: thanks @pptaszni - but why specifically does option 1 look better?

Comment: Opinion-based, it just looks uncomfortable for me to ask a user to specify the day of the week by name each time. Especially when he doesn't care which day it is and he needs some generic statistic (available for each day). Also, if days of the week are named, maybe there is also need to distinguish the day of the months, or holidays? That's why I prefer 1st interface.

Comment: Just uncomfortable passing in a large struct with optional values to the generic API - ```struct AllInfoStruct {
  std::optional<MondayStatsInfo> monday_info; 
  ...
} ```

Comment: Yeah, but it doesn't have to be `std::optional`; It can be `std::unordered_map`, or `nlohmann:json`, or sth else like parsable `std::string`.

Comment: Why not use `std::variant`? Something like `auto todayData = DailyStatsLib::GetStats(today); std::visit(..., todayData)`

Comment: @Genjutsu - `todayData` is something that needs to be built from outside DailyStatsLib.
It needs to be built in the `main` function.
I could do something like: `auto todayData = DailyStatsLib::GetStats(all_info_struct);`, but then I'll still be creating a `all_info_struct`

Comment: Option 1, why not make `all_info_struct` a `variant<MonStat, TueStat, WedStat....>` if only 1 info should be available?

Comment: @Ranoiaetep - only one is available, but I don't know which one. The only way I can know which one is by checking - `if(today == e_day_Monday){ //then build MonStat }`

Comment: Why not both? It's not uncommon for libraries to offer multiple levels of abstraction so that the user can use both premade high-level API or construct own one from smaller library components. STL and boost frequently have lots of layers, many of which are a part of public interface. I would try to offer as granular public interface as possible (unless it compromises performance) and give examples how the library and the user is able to build more high-level ones from it.